# Combine DATE_FORMAT() and MONTH() in query

Tags: mysql

I need to get some statistics from a database, where usage of tablets is stored, so I use:

```
$statistiek = "SELECT MONTH(datum) as month,YEAR(datum)as year, SUM(android) as androidtotal,SUM(ios) as iostotal,SUM(windows) as windowstotal FROM reservaties GROUP BY YEAR(datum),MONTH(datum)";
```

so I can now how much of each kind is used each month.

However, I'd like to display the months in `mm` format, not `m` like it is now. (So March is `03` not `3`)

I tried `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MONTH(datum), '%m') as month, ...` and some variations on that, but I keep getting an error or the date in `m` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
$statistiek = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%m') as month, 
  YEAR(datum)as year, SUM(android) as androidtotal,
  SUM(ios) as iostotal,SUM(windows) as windowstotal
  FROM reservaties GROUP BY YEAR(datum),MONTH(datum)";
```

You cannot extract the month first and then call `DATE_FORMAT` on just a single number. You have to call it on the full date.

Comment: No I did not try that, but I did now and it worked. Thank you very much.